# Symfony5 forms: how to disable "required" for all fields by default?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

## Description

Symfony has `required = true` for all input fields by default:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#required

And I'm searching for means to disable this behaviour.

## Findings

### 1. Explicit required=false

Of course, the simplest one is to pass `['required' => false]` to each and every field. But this is somewhat unwieldy.

### 2. Helper class

Then, I created a helper class to build forms tweaked for my needs. It was simply appending `['required' => false]` to every field. It works - except for submit button or alike - for them Symfony throws an error:

```
Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Exception\UndefinedOptionsException: The option "required" does not exist. Defined options are: "attr", "attr_translation_parameters", "auto_initialize", ...
```

I tried to find a way to get the list of available options for fields - but they are well-hidden, failed to uncover them.

### 3. required=false to the form

I also tried to put `['required' => false]` into the very top form. Well... it behaves strangely:

- If I don't pass this option to the form, or if I write `['required' => true]`, then for each individual field I can override it to `['required' => false]`
- If I pass `['required' => false]` to the form, then I can't override it with `['required' => true]` for any field - all of them are somehow forced to `['required' => false]`

## Questions

So, is there a right method to solve the issue? It could be some `method()` for getting available options for specific fields - so I could skip setting `required` for fields without it. Or some approach that I don't know about.

## Edit 1

Tried the solution written in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65825111/982746

This is my test code:

```php
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../../lib/vendor/autoload.php';

use \Symfony\Component\Form\Forms;
use \Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type as T;



class NotRequiredExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension {
    public static function getExtendedTypes (): iterable {
        return [T\FormType::class];
    }

    public function configureOptions ($resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefault('required', false);
    }
}



$builder = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
    ->addTypeExtension(new \NotRequiredExtension())
    ->getFormFactory()
    ->createBuilder(T\FormType::class, ['inherit'=>'', 'required_true'=>'', 'required_false'=>''])
;

$form = $builder
    ->add('inherit',        T\TextType::class)
    ->add('required_true',  T\TextType::class, ['required'=>true])
    ->add('required_false', T\TextType::class, ['required'=>false])
    ->getForm()
;

$formView = $form->createView();

var_dump($formView->children['inherit']->vars['required']); //false
var_dump($formView->children['required_true']->vars['required']); //false
var_dump($formView->children['required_false']->vars['required']); //false
```

Seems it doesn't work - similar to my **experiment #3**: if I set `required=false` to the form type, symfony then refuses to change `required` to `true` for any individual field - all of the `var_dump()`s display `false`.

Comment: I tried The TypeExtension, and It worked fine with me, make sure there is no other extension, override your default, you can add lower priority to your extension to make sure , It will be the last

Answer (score 4):

You can create form extension `AbstractTypeExtension`.

```
namespace App\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class NoRequiredExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefault('required', false);
    }

    public static function getExtendedTypes(): iterable
    {
        return [FormType::class];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but please see my "Edit 1" I added in the original question - I tried your solution, but to no avail.